# "The transaction response cannot be null" Error on PayU WebCheckout

Tags: payu

I'm integrating PayU's WebCheckOut for a simple payment in a website with vb.net, i've followed all the instructions on http://developers.payulatam.com/es/web_checkout/integration.html and right now i'm trying to test the payments, response and confirmation through the sandbox (The POST is directed to https://sandbox.checkout.payulatam.com/ppp-web-gateway-payu), but i can't get past the payment because of this error:

[image: PayU Unspecified Error]

And i haven't found any insight anywere on the cause, the error is shown after filling all the payment data and clicking the "pay" button, have this happend to anyone?, thanks in advance!

Comment: This might refer to the responseUrl form-param, otherwise PayU doesn't have a 'callback' URL to respond to.